# Configuration to get the images from the apache

Tags: apache, tomcat6

I have multiple Tomcat servers. In each tomcat I am loading all images. I want to move the images from Tomcat to Apache and access the images from there.

My question is: is there any configuration to get the images in a Java web application from Apache instead of Tomcat?

Comment: You miss one crucial fact: images are not requested by server, but by client. The request happens by HTTP URL. You just have to modify the image URL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - images are shown by resolving their URL, and in most cases it is relative to the current page.

But you can use mod_proxy (or mod_jk) to use all your tomcats through Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Hide your tomcat servers behind an apache server and then you can do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName      www.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html
    ProxyPass       /img    !
    ProxyPass       /       ajp://localhost:1234/
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache will serve /img from /var/www/html/img and other requests will be sent to tomcat. This configuration needs mod_proxy_ajp apache module to be active. Tomcat must listen to AJP requests on the given port, use:

```
<Connector port="1234" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" address="127.0.0.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

And configure tomcat to serve www.example.com or the default virtual host.

```
<Host
    name="www.example.com"
    appBase="/path/to/tomcat/apps/www.example.com"
    unpackWARs="true"
    autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false"
    xmlNamespaceAware="false"
/>
```

or

```
<Host
    name="localhost"
    appBase="/path/to/tomcat/apps/www.example.com"
    unpackWARs="true"
    autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false"
    xmlNamespaceAware="false"
/>
```

Deploy your webapp to /path/to/tomcat/apps/www.example.com/ as ROOT.war, this should be enough to have the whole setup up and running.